# "Couldn't change keyring password" error in Seahorse

Tags: keyrings, seahorse

when I try to change the password of every Password Keyring in Ubuntu 12.10 I receive this error message:

> Couldn't change keyring password
>
> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Secret.Error.NoSuchObject: The collection does not exist

The software is:

seahorse 3.6.0

This is something strange, I never had this problem with previous Ubuntu releases.

Can you help me?
My intention is to have a blank password keyring.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. here is the relevant bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1048484

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: There's already a bug report for this and the fix is apparently on the way.
Perhaps increasing the number of people reporting that they are affected can help speed up the process ;-)